# Symfony LDAP log in automatically

Tags: symfony, authentication, ldap, credentials

I have set up Symfony with LDAP authentication and it works just fine.

Since people are logged in on their computers with just the same credentials, I'm wondering if there's a way to pass those credentials through to Symfony so that the user doesnt have to log in manually anymore.

Hopefully, someone can help me out. :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called SingleSignOn or SSO. It usually uses something like Kerberos which in turn can use LDAP as backend to store the passwords and the user-informations.

But it usually requires specifically adapted WebServers and Browsers to work out as expected. If you are working in a plain Windows-Environment with IE as Browser and IIS as Webserver it might be easier to implement than in a mixed environment.

I'd suggest you ask your favourite search-engine for SSO or Kerberos and I'm sure you'll find some solutions. I've done a quick search myself which turned up this:

- [Kerberos authentication with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147843/kerberos-authentication-with-symfony2)
- http://share.ez.no/forums/general/automatic-user-logon-sso-with-active-directory-ldap-ntlm
- [Authentication into Symfony 2.0 from an external System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441570/authentication-into-symfony-2-0-from-an-external-system)